# JQuery selector issue on IE7 for input tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have couple of forms with different ids but with same input names and ids. For example:

```
<form id="form1>
    <input name="email" id="email" value="test@test.com"/>
     ..... 
</form>
<form id="form2>
    <input name="email" id="email" value="test@test.com"/>
     ..... 
</form>
```

And  in my Jquery ready function I have below code. This works fine in FireFox, Chrome but not in IE7. That is alert function showing email value as "test@test.com" in FireFox, Chrome but IE7 showing as "undefined". Any suggestions?

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
        alert($("#form1 #emailAddress").val());
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate IDs are invalid, and I wouldn't count on any selector filtering to work in the current, past, or future versions of jQuery. Those elements shouldn't have ids, and they should be selected by name.

e.g:

`$('#form1 [name=email]')`
`$('#form2 [name=email]')`

Comment: fiddled http://jsfiddle.net/62m3y/ selector filtering does work in the past and current versions of jquery, and most likely will continue to work.  while it may not be the best practice w/o having to make changes to the design, it does work.

Comment: @Patrick: Try  alert($("#form2>#email").val()); this will fail

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
      alert($("#email","#form1").val());
 });
```

Test this code

Answer (score -2):

seeing that your input name and id both are simply "email".... and in your selector you have emailAddress... that IS going to give you an undefined.

Try something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
alert($("#form1>#email").val());     
});
```